# Cannot enable Wi-Fi

Tags: wireless, wifi-hardware-switch

Yesterday my laptop shut down because battery ran out. Next time I turned it on I couldn't enable Wi-Fi. I tried to enable it with:

```
rfkill unblock all
```

but it's still not working. Please help.

EDIT:
rfkill list printed this:

```
0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

ip link printed this:

```
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 88:ae:1d:e8:4e:ea brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    3: wlp7s0b1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 4c:ed:de:0c:5c:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: Try to run `sudo service network-manager restart`

Comment: Please edit your question and post output of `rfkill list` and `ip link` commands.

Comment: @Pilot6 I tried, but nothing changed

Comment: Try resetting BIOS to defaults

Comment: @Jeremy31 Didn't help

Comment: @Marcipanko please edit your question to include the make and model of your computer.

Comment: @Pilot6 's comment worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Your WiFi and Bluetooth Devices are hard-blocked...

There is a network-switch/button/key on your computer/laptop which could be switched `OFF` - means that your network hardware is disabled (hard-blocked)...

Find it and switch it `ON`...

Comment: Once when I opened my laptop I accidentally did something so these function buttons and mouse aren't working. However, Wi-Fi worked just fine afterwards and I can also use 'FN+F8' to turn on/off Wi-Fi, but it just changes 'soft: yes/no'. Is there any way to do it from command line?

Comment: I don't think that you can do it with the command line, hard blocked means disabled by hardware switch... what kind of laptop do you have?

Comment: I have Tosihba Satellite A660

Comment: Give me the output of: lspci -nn | grep 'Network controller'! If it's Broadcom then try this: sudo modprobe -v brcmsmac, while the wifi indicator light should be illuminated

Comment: It is Broadcom, didn't work though.

Comment: Well, then I'm at the end with my latin...if nothing else works, reinstall your ubuntu...sorry