# Cannot enable Ralink wifi in ubuntu 16.04 in hp pavillion

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, hp, ralink

I know this question has been asked before, but so far no luck with any of the answers, I will link all the threads I have tried.

### The problem

But first the problem, My wifi suddenly stopped working, and when I try to enable it, this happens:

[image]

As you can see when I try to enable the wifi it slides just back in:

### Diagnostics

This are some of the diagnostics I run:

Following the advice in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784025/cannot-enable-wi-fi) question, I run the following code

```
rfkill list
```

Which printed this:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

and running this

```
ip link
```

prints this:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether a0:1d:48:f8:ad:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 48:5a:b6:c4:9c:93 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Then I run the diagnostics recommended in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/946235/unable-to-activate-enable-wireless) link:

first this code:

```
lspci -v
```

Which printed this

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
    DeviceName: Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi Adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at b2410000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
    Kernel modules: rt2800pci
```

and this code:

```
sudo lshw -C network *-network
```

Which printed this:

```
Hardware Lister (lshw) - B.02.17
usage: lshw [-format] [-options ...]
       lshw -version

    -version        print program version (B.02.17)

format can be
    -html           output hardware tree as HTML
    -xml            output hardware tree as XML
    -short          output hardware paths
    -businfo        output bus information

options can be
    -class CLASS    only show a certain class of hardware
    -C CLASS        same as '-class CLASS'
    -c CLASS        same as '-class CLASS'
    -disable TEST   disable a test (like pci, isapnp, cpuid, etc. )
    -enable TEST    enable a test (like pci, isapnp, cpuid, etc. )
    -quiet          don't display status
    -sanitize       sanitize output (remove sensitive information like serial numbers, etc.)
    -numeric        output numeric IDs (for PCI, USB, etc.)
```

Finally following this question the output of the following code

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; dmesg | grep iwl
```

is this:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    DeviceName: Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi Adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
```

### First try

Following the advice in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784025/cannot-enable-wi-fi) question, I tried this:

#### a)

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

That did not work and then

#### b)

```
rfkill unblock all
```

but it keeps the hard block

### Second try

Following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013573/wifi-adapter-wont-enable-in-a-fresh-ubuntu-16-04-lts-install) question I tried the wireless button on my hp pavillion, but the only thing it did was to turn on the airplane mode

Comment: The hard block means **hardware** block, i.e., a switch, a key (typically one of the function keys) or a key combo.

Comment: Hello @GabrielaGarcia, I tried to push the wireless button on my Pavillion, it turned the airplane mode on